# How to customize the left side-bar in Magento 1.9 category view

Tags: magento, sidebar

I am trying to customize my left side-bar in Magento when the frontend shows a certain category. For example I want to remove the Newsletter box and a custom block which was added by the theme developer.

However I am not able to find the correct file to edit in order for being able to customize apropriately.

Comment: Do you want to customize it for one category only, or for all?

Comment: For all, basically I want to create a default left sidebar for all category views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do this with XML, by updating your local.xml file.

```
 <catalog_category_default>
    <reference name="left">
       <remove name="left.newsletter"/>
    </reference>
 <catalog_category_default>
```

Refernce for removing common items in Magento: http://myphpinformation.blogspot.in/2015/05/remove-default-magneto-block-like-news.html

Answer (score 0):

you can get better idea about how block is rendered in frontend by just setting 
Template Path Hints => yes,you find it at in adminpanel under configuaration menu 
in developer tab.

Remove corresponding block file or just commenting it in layout file and make clear
cache in order to reflect your change.

Thanks

Comment: thanks! which item to i have to click in the developer tab? allow symlinks? theres no such thing as "Template Path Hints"

Comment: In developer tab you can see debug dropdown tab upper right in the page. and if not visible please do select the name of store from left upper right Current Configuration Scope: and then it will be visible.

Comment: thanks, that worked. however i dont see the right path on my frontend now. there has to be a file which declares every block like newsletter, custom block, product compare block etc to be shown, hasnt it?
for example in the code it says "block-subscribe" for the newsletter, but the local.xml doesnt have this code